# SIGSTOP not working in c program

Tags: c, linux, process, signals

I am trying to write a C program in which the parent process suspends the child process and after a few seconds continues executing it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void sigstop(); 
void sigcont();
void sigquit();

int main()
{ 
   int pid; 
   if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (pid == 0)
     { /* child */
       signal(SIGSTOP,sigstop);
       signal(SIGCONT,sigcont);
       signal(SIGQUIT, sigquit);
       for(;;); /* loop for ever */
     }
     else {
        printf("\nPARENT: sending SIGSTOP to suspend the process\n\n");
        kill(pid, SIGSTOP);
        sleep(5);
        printf("\nPARENT: sending SIGCONT to continue the suspended process\n\n");
        kill(pid, SIGCONT);
        sleep(5);
        printf("killing child");
        kill(pid,SIGQUIT);
        sleep(5);
     }
}

void sigstop()
{  
   printf("CHILD: I've been suspended\n");
}

void sigcont()
{  
   printf("CHILD: I'm back\n");
}

void sigquit()
{ 
    printf("My DADDY has Killed me!!!\n");
    exit(0);
}
```

`printf` inside `sigstop()` never gets executed and `sigquit()` gets called before `printf("killing child");`. How does this happen and how can I get output in proper order ?

Comment: `SIGQUIT` does not _kill_ a process. That would be `SIGKILL`.

Comment: Calling `printf()` in a signal handler invokes undefined behavior.  Only async-signal-safe functions can be safely called from within a signal handler: *the behavior is undefined ... if the signal handler calls any function defined in this standard other than one of the functions listed in the following table*.  See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04_03_03

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you [read the `signal(7)` manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) you will see that

> The signals `SIGKILL` and `SIGSTOP` cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.

You simply can not catch that signal.

---

The last bit, about `"Killing child"` get printed in the wrong order is very easy to fix: Add a trailing newline to the string you print.

This is because output to `stdout` (which is what `printf` writes to) is by default *line-buffered*. This means that the internal buffer of `stdout` is *flushed* (i.e. actually written to the terminal) on a newline. If you don't have the newline, then the buffer will be flushed when the process exits, which is after you exit the child process.